# Display Instagram User "Follower Count" - Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I already have a plugin that let's users authenticate into their wordpress account, and that plugin displays the users recent photos.

**I also want to pull in their follower count.**

I've tried going through the API and my plugin code to find the right snipper to insert, but haven't found a solution yet.

Here is the plugin JS file, can someone help me?

```js
(function( $ ) {
 'use strict';

 jQuery(document).ready(function(){


  // Init
  um_instagram_get_photos();

  /**
   * Init Gallery
   */
  function um_setup_instagram_gallery(){
   // Show first 5 instagram photos on load
   jQuery('#um-ig-photo-wrap ul li:gt(5)').addClass('hidden');
   var $ul_gallery  = jQuery('ul#um-ig-show_photos');
   var $nav_previous  = jQuery('#um-ig-content .um-ig-photo-navigation a.nav-left');
   var $nav_next   = jQuery('#um-ig-content .um-ig-photo-navigation a.nav-right');
   var $um_paginate  = jQuery('.um-ig-paginate span');
   var gallery_page  = $ul_gallery.find('li:not(.hidden) img').length;
   var total_photos  = $ul_gallery.attr('data-photos-count');
   var is_viewing      = $ul_gallery.attr('data-viewing');
   var paginate   = 1;
   var max_photos   = 18;
   var items_per_page  = 6;
   
   // Hide previous button on load
   $nav_previous.addClass('nav-hide');

   // Show paginate on load
   $um_paginate.text( gallery_page +'/'+total_photos );
   
   // Hide Next button last page reached
   if( total_photos < items_per_page ){
    $nav_next.addClass('nav-hide');
   }
   
   // Previous
   $nav_previous.on('click',function() {
    
     paginate--;
        
        var current_visible_photos = $ul_gallery.find('li:not(.hidden) img').length;
        
        var first = $ul_gallery.find('li:not(.hidden)').first();
        first.prevAll(':lt('+items_per_page+')').removeClass('hidden');
        first.prev().nextAll().addClass('hidden');
     
         gallery_page -= current_visible_photos;
         
        if( total_photos > items_per_page && total_photos > gallery_page  ){
         $nav_next.removeClass('nav-hide');
     }

     if( gallery_page == items_per_page ){
      $nav_previous.addClass('nav-hide');
     }
         
     
        $um_paginate.text( gallery_page +'/'+total_photos );

   });

   // Next
   $nav_next.on('click',function() {
    
    paginate++;

    var last = $ul_gallery.find('li:not(.hidden)').last();
       last.nextAll(':lt('+items_per_page+')').removeClass('hidden');
    last.next().prevAll().addClass('hidden');

    var current_visible_photos = $ul_gallery.find('li:not(.hidden) img').length;
    gallery_page += current_visible_photos;
      
       
       if( total_photos > gallery_page  ){
         $nav_next.removeClass('nav-hide');
    }

    if( total_photos == gallery_page  ){
         $nav_next.addClass('nav-hide');
    }
    
    $nav_previous.removeClass('nav-hide');
       
       $um_paginate.text(gallery_page+'/'+total_photos );
    
   });

   // Disconnecet instagram account
   jQuery('.um-ig-photos_disconnect').on('click',function(){
    jQuery('.um-ig-photos_metakey').val('');
    jQuery('.um-form form').submit();
   });


   // Add photo opacity effects on hover
   jQuery("#um-ig-photo-wrap a img").hover(function(){
       jQuery(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 0.7});
   },function(){
       jQuery(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 1});
   });
  }

  /**
   * Ajax get instagram photos
   */
  function um_instagram_get_photos(){
   
   var $um_photo_wrap = jQuery('#um-ig-photo-wrap');
   var metakey = $um_photo_wrap.attr('data-metakey');
   var viewing = $um_photo_wrap.attr('data-viewing');
   var $body_classes = jQuery('body').attr('class');
   var user_id = 0;
   var cl =  $body_classes.split(' ');
     
   if( cl.length > 0 ){
    jQuery.each(cl,function(i,cs){
     if( cs.substr(0,14) == "um-profile-id-" ){
      user_id = cs.substr(14);
     }
    })
   }

   jQuery('#um-ig-preload').css('background','url('+um_instagram.image_loader+') no-repeat  50% 50%');
   
   if( viewing == 'true' ){
    jQuery.ajax({
     method: 'POST',
     url: um_scripts.instagram_get_photos,
     data:{
      metakey: metakey,
      viewing: viewing,
      um_user_id: user_id
     },
     success: function( response ){
      $um_photo_wrap.html( response.photos );
      um_setup_instagram_gallery();
      um_instagram_preload();
     },
     error: function( e ){
      console.log(e);
     }

    });
   }else if( viewing == 'false' ){ // Edit profile view
    um_setup_instagram_gallery();
    um_instagram_preload();
   }
  }
  
  /**
   * Lazy load
   */
  function um_instagram_preload(){
   // Remove preload
   setTimeout( function(){
    jQuery("#um-ig-preload").fadeOut();
    jQuery("#um-ig-content").fadeIn();
   }, 5000);
  }
 });

 

})( jQuery );
```